# Trying to get size of csv file as an integer in Kotlin, keeps returning 0

Tags: csv, kotlin, for-loop, parsing, size

I am studying Kotlin in my final year of university however im quite new to the language. Im trying to read the length of a csv file into an integer so it can be used in a for loop to check for duplicates. However, using .size returns 0 and i have also tried using csvParser and a for loop.
Ill attach the section of code below!

Thanks for any help!

```
 val bufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file))
            val csvParser = CSVParser(
                bufferedReader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                    .withFirstRecordAsHeader() // escape the first line
                    .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
                    .withTrim()
            )
            var bool = false
            val tempTime = timeParser(
                startTime,
                endTime
            )
            val x = 0

            for (csvRecord in csvParser) {
                val x = x + 1

                val programme = csvRecord.get(2);
                val year = csvRecord.get(3);
                val term = csvRecord.get(4);

                

                 //parsing time from String to array of int [startHH, start mm, endHH, end mm]

                if (moduleList[x].programme == programme && moduleList[x].year == year && moduleList[x].term == term) {
                   
                    val time = timeParser(moduleList[x].startTime, moduleList[x].endTime)
                   
                    //checking for time overlapping
                    if (tempTime[0] == time[0] || tempTime[0] > time[0] || tempTime[0] < time[2]) {
                        println("There is a collision with" + moduleList[x].modID + moduleList[x].name)
                        bool = true


                    }

                }
            }

            return bool
        }
```

Using this code i get index out of bounds because the csv length is apparently 0 ^

Comment: You’re shadowing the variable x instead of incrementing it. You’re also skipping x=0.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, ive unshadowed x now, however still getting this error:        
                                                                                                                             
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0